# com.microsoft.azure.eventhubs.EventHubException: connection aborted

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

try to connect to event hub but got this error.

connection str 
Endpoint=sb://stevtresr.servicebus.windows.net;EntityPath=test;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=8rFZIuOasdsdsdYzjmhUEXT+gGI1wJQ2PVMeJ6emvg+z87MQ=

already disabled firewall

Comment: I hope it's not your real shared access key

Comment: Thanks for the kind reminder.